# C# shift several columns in a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, shift, dimension

I want to shift my array (two dim.) like a stack.
Every column should be shifted parallel (same steps, same direction).

array before         array after shifting

1   11   21            2   12   22
2   12   22            3   13   23
3   13   23            4   14   24
4   14   24            5   15   25
5   15   25            0   0   0

I tried array.copy, but it copies the array as is it would be a single dimension array. So it will mess up the shifting in the other columns. Anybody know how to do this...without using loops over the whole array :D

Comment: That looks like a one-dimensional array to me. Can you correct your formatting, please?

Comment: Stacks don't shift so that's not a helpful description.

Comment: Could you post some code, maybe on how you create your 'multi-dimensional array'?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - you have the points to do that. Always take a peek if it's missing info or a markdown problem.

Comment: @user3038335 - just 2 dimensons or do you also want his for 3+ ?  Your example shifts columns, not dimensions.

Comment: use a `List<>` instead, just remove the top items and add the empty items to mimic a shifting behavior.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I did look into the source code. I didn't find an easy way to correct the issue, though, not knowing any table-related markdown syntax, and thus referred this back to the OP.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: sorry...yes just two dimensions and shifting columns ;)

Answer (score 2):

Simply using arrays.

```
int[,] array = new int[,]
{
    {1, 11, 12}, {2, 21, 22}, {3, 31, 33} 
};

for (int i = 1; i < array.GetUpperBound(0) + 1; i++ )
{
    for(int j=0; j < array.GetUpperBound(1) +1; j++)
    {
        if (i == array.GetUpperBound(0))
        {
            array[i, j] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            array[i - 1, j] = array[i, j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...without using loops over the whole array :D

Comment: Oops, missed that. Still, it's an answer. Not the one you needed. :)

Comment: The 'without loops' req is non-constructive. At best you can hide the loops in some Linq or lib methods.